# How to use IF Else in store procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute Select query with ID parameter, now if ID is empty then I want All Rows, otherwise only row which contains this ID,
So far, I have created this Store Procedure,

```
IF(@CustId = null)
  Begin
   Select * from tblCustomer
  End
Else
  Begin
   Select * from tblCustomer where custID=@custID
  End
```

When I am executing this query with ID, I am getting result but when I am passing, I am not getting any result. What's correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Null is handled differently than other values, you need to use

```
IF (@CustId IS NULL)
```

Your current code of `IF(@CustId = null)` will always evaluate to False, so the else case will be executed regardless of what you pass for `@CustId`.  **[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172138%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** goes into more detail about how to handle NULL values: